# Make XmlPullParser ignore whitespace?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am parsing Xml with an XmlPullParser. I just want to deal with the Xml tags and the text contained within them however, the XmlPullParser reads in the whitespace text (spaces and carriage returns) between tags. Can it be set to ignore this whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used XmlPullParser before (so apologies if this is totally wrong) but having a glance at the javadocs, it seems like when you call [nextToken()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#nextToken%28%29) you'll have to look at the return value and skip over [IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE) .

The following was inappropriate (thanks [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8844/jeff-hubbard)): <strike>BTW are you being forced to use XmlPullParser? Based on what it **sounds** like you're trying to achieve, I'd consider a higher level API like [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). I generally use [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding), but that's not by choice haha.</strike>

Comment: He's probably using a pull parser due to memory constraints. I'm not sure if you're familiar with Android, but parsing large XML documents isn't possible with a full in-memory AST--you have to use pull parsing to handle anything over a certain size.

Comment: Is the actual suggestion as to what he can do with XmlPullParser correct, or is there a nicer way? Clearly I'm used to dealing with servers not handsets haha :) Fun!

Comment: Depending on how big his document is (and if he went for a pull parser, it's likely big), then pull parsing is probably the best way to handle it. As for skipping whitespace, I'm not sure. I never had to deal with large enough xml documents to have problems with it (my bane was JSON).

Comment: Yes I think I will just have to manually skip the ignorable whitespace, I was hoping there was a setting that would automatically skip it. The XML documents I'm parsing are actually tiny but I'm using XmlPullParser as it's what Google recommend for Android - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Answer (score 1):

IDK if there's a setting to ignore white space.  If you keep track of the current node as a string you can code to ignore white space.  If the current node is blank then just ignore the text.  My testing revealed it was just escaped line feeds and such.  I optimized around it as follows.  **Danger This works on the xml I'm using it might not work on yours**

```
String N="";  // Yes I know its Capitalized but its the Current Node and very important to keep track of.


if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
    N = xpp.getName();//save the name of the node.

...

} else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
    N = "";//clear the name of the node.
} else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
    //if the name of the node is not blank then process it
if (!N.equals("")) {
        //I have a node so process it
    }
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Adding a late answer after looking for a solution myself.

The parser has a `isWhiteSpace()`method.  It can only be called on Text related event types (e.g. `TEXT`, `CDSECT`, `IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE`) otherwise it will throw.

You can get the eventype by calling either `next` which advances the parser or `getEventType`.

Calling `next` automatically skips over the `IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE` event.  This event type is only hit when calling `nextToken` which is more fine grained and hits all event types .  Even though we're skipping "ignoreable" whitespace by calling next, the parser still finds nearly all whitespace unignoreable, and thus needs you're permission to skip it.

```
    boolean isEoD = false;

    do{
        switch (parser.next()){

            default:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                if(!parser.isWhitespace())  //Throws if called on wrong eventType
                    System.out.println("Text: " + parser.getText());

                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                System.out.println("TAG: " + parser.getName()+ "\n");
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:
                isEoD = true;
        }
    }while(!isEoD);
```